# Apache POI 4.1.2 Migration issue with CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC

Tags: migration, poi-hssf, hssf, apache-poi-4

I had POI 3.17 before in my project and as the black duck scan resutl was shwoing vulnerability I had to switch to 4.0 or better. After I downloaded the 4.1.2 jar ( THIS IS A ANT PROJECT). I am having build issues which says this :

Compiling 500 source files to C:\Users\k\project\ts\ts\build\WEB-INF\classes
    C:\Users\k\project\ts\ts\tool\src\com\vh\tool\services\DNBBatchThread.java:197: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]

if (cell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
                                  ^

Comment: THE "^" is under the "." after "HSSFCell"

Answer (score 0):

As of today(24th April 2020)  , the latest version of POI is 4.1.2
In latest version , the `getCellType()` method returns `CellType` Enum.  So your code should be like below.

```
switch (cell.getCellType()) {

   case NUMERIC:
                 //Do Something
                 break;
   case STRING:
                 //Do something
                 break;

}
```

Note:  In the above case statements , NUMERIC and STRING are of type `CellType` enum values.